# How to add just one event listener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Going back to javascript after years of polymer and react and this little gem has got me stumped, I'm trying to make a little library that can be included in my customer's web pages.

```
"use strict";
const MyLib = mylib();
function mylib() {
  const res = {
    init:(data) => {
        const doSomthing = () => {
         console.log('somthing', data)
        }
        const btn = document.getElementById('my-btn');
        
        console.log('REMOVING EVENT LISTENER')
        btn.removeEventListener('click', doSomthing, false);

        console.log('ADDING EVENT LISTENER')
        btn.addEventListener('click', doSomthing, false);
    }
  };
  return res;
}
```

if then if I call `MyLib.init({some: 'data'})` twice I expect just one event listener to be on `my-btn` but there is 2, I don't get it?

Comment: `doSomthing` is a new function so it can't be removed like that.

Comment: Is mylib running twice to create these multiple event listeners, or something? If so you'd have to define doSomthing outside the it, or outside the init function anyway, so it doesn't become a different reference each time. It only has scope within the init function, so you can't ask for an event listener to be removed which was added during a previous run of a function, because it was referencing a different `doSomthing` and therefore removeEventListener won't find the right thing.

Comment: Thanks, could you expand on why and how? I could move it outside of init but not outside MyLib, doSomthing still needs access to data

Comment: I think I posted my comment at about the same moment as you asked for an expanded explanation. Does my comment help, or is there still something you don't understand?

Comment: yes it helped allot, thank you